# What is the minimal number of edges for a polygonal knot to be nontrivial?

Tags: knot-theory

I started learning about knots from Manturov's monograph. Exercise 2.1 says "Show that all polygonal links with less than six edges are trivial". I kind of convince myself why this should hold. Then Exercise 2.2 says "Draw a polygonal trefoil knot with six edges". I start drawing and draw it with five edges. Am I missing something or there was a typo?

Comment: could you include an image of your drawing? Note that for a polygonal knot, you need that it can be realised as a polygon in $\mathbb{R}^3$, not only drawn on paper.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the point - I drew a diagram of the trefoil with five edges, but it apparently cannot be embedded in three-space.